# How can I open url by clicking on hyperlink in CMD?

Tags: python, cmd, hyperlink

I wanna print some links to cmd and directly from cmd open these links by clicking on it. How can I do this?

Comment: This depends on your terminal.  And many other things as well.

Comment: Windows 10 CMD command line

Answer (score 0):

Sorry, I do not think it is possible by clicking on them but I can tell you you can use this to open some page in the browser:

```
import webbrowser 

url = “http://google.com/“

webbrowser.open(url)
```

Comment: Try just printing the url and clicking on it, see if that works. (If you don’t know how to stop it from closing do import time and then time.sleep(5) this will delay 5 seconds

Answer (score 0):

The command line just doesn't support that kind of interaction <sup>AFAIk</sup>

What you can do is use `webbrowser.open` to open a link in your default web browser like this:

```
import webbrowser
if input('type yes to open in browser').lower() == 'yes':
    webbrowser.open(my_link_var)
```

What's nice about `webbrowser.open` is that it is fully cross platform.